# Trying to get to grips with the DAC-08

Tags: dac

I'm trying to get my head around the DAC-08.  I have so far come up with this circuit as a test:
[image]

However - it is not producing the results I would expect.

Here's what it does:

U1 created a square-wave clock signal to drive U2 which is a binary counter.  The output of this heads into the DAC-08's (U4) data inputs.  I have buffered the signal through U3 because I noticed during my experimentations that the outputs of U2 don't always have the exact same voltage.  U3 should be redundant in this circuit.  I had it there mainly when I replaced the DAC-08 with am R/2R ladder to test the rest of the circuit.  The output of the DAC-08 is then fed through an op-amp in voltage follower mode.

Now, I'd expect a nice triangle wave form out of this, and that is (roughly) what I got with the R/2R ladder.

However, what I get from the DAC-08 is something more like this:

[image][image]

I have tried playing around with the order of the data pins, and it seems to always come up with the same (or similar) waveform.  Now, I'm new to the DAC-08, and I don't fully understand what all the pins do - and the data sheet fails to mention it either, so there is something I am missing.  I have gone through a number of example applications, but none of them have shed any light on this.

Does anyone have any experience with the DAC-08?  Can anyone point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Triangle waveform or sawtooth?

Comment: sorry, yes, saw-tooth.  My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DAC08 also won't work properly without a negative supply voltage, in addition to the above mentioned problem.  The '08 output sinks current, so ideally it should drive a transimpedance amplifier, which you can make by connecting IOUT to the inverting input, noninverting to ground, and a gain resistor between the output and the inverting input. The output voltage will then be IOUT*R, where IOUT is set by the reference current and the binary input as described in the datasheet. If the output op amp being used in a transimpedance configuration isn't going to share the negative supply, it needs to have a common mode input voltage range that includes ground.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can leave /IOUT output dangling. Actually IOUT is a current output, so you also need some resistor to ground from IOUT. Take a look at the [datasheet](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~barbeau/SDR/BF537/DAC08.pdf), figures 30 and 31 - one of these applications is what you need.

Also, I don't think that VREF+/- can be directly tied to VCC/GND - see figure 24. You need to connect these pins via resistors, controlling the reference current.

You may also want to take a look at a complete [application](http://www.filety.pl/arty/sprzet/edw/covox/rys2.png). It's a good, old Covox sound "card", I had one attached to my 286 long ago :)

**Update**: useful app notes:

- [AN-1525 from National](http://www.national.com/an/AN/AN-1525.pdf)
- [AN-17 from Analog Devices](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/80635169AN17.pdf)

Comment: Indeed, looking at the datasheet again, it requires negative supply.

Comment: @Czajnik Sorry to leave your comment hanging! I added another answer.

Comment: @Bitrex No worries :) BTW, see the appnote from National above - it describes how to use DAC-08 with a single power supply.

Comment: Hmmm... That's [single supply] starting to get as bulky as an R/2R ladder.   Maybe I'll just scrap the DAC and stick to a ladder - it's so much simpler...

Comment: @Matt Jenkins perhaps you should look for a single-supply DAC, and DAC-08 is way old btw. What are you trying to build?

Comment: A DAC-08 is what I have to hand - I ripped it from an old UPS.  I'm not trying to build anything - just experimenting with it.